# ActionController::API in Rails 4 application with both API and Web views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-api

I have a Rails 4.2.7 application with both web views and a JSON API. There are separate base controllers for web views and API. I'd like the API base controller to inherit from `ActionController::API`. However, in Rails 4 `ActionController::API` is implemented in the `rails-api` gem and I'm using the standard `rails` gem.

I have attempted to create an `ActionController::API` "clone" by inheriting from `ActionController::Metal` and including all modules that are included in `ActionController::API` (see the source for `rails-api` [here](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/e150fb9555a1de863711055308a066f607d6edab/lib/rails-api/action_controller/api.rb#L125) and `rails` 5 [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L111)). The resulting code is:

```
class Api::V1::BaseApiController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include ActionController::UrlFor
  include ActionController::Redirecting
  # originally ApiRendering
  include ActionController::Rendering
  include ActionController::Renderers::All
  include ActionController::ConditionalGet
  include ActionController::RackDelegation
  # Originally BasicImplicitRender
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::StrongParameters
  include ActionController::ForceSSL
  include ActionController::DataStreaming
  # Before callbacks should also be executed as early as possible so
  # also include them at the bottom.
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  # Append rescue at the bottom to wrap as much as possible.
  include ActionController::Rescue
  # Params wrapper should come before instrumentation so they are
  # properly showed in logs
  include ActionController::ParamsWrapper
  # Add instrumentations hooks at the bottom to ensure they instrument
  # all the methods properly.
  include ActionController::Instrumentation

  # base API controller code here
end
```

It seems to be working, but I'd like to validate this solution with more experienced developers. Is it OK to use this as a replacement of `ActionController::API`?

Thanks in advance.